# Can I use Boost libraries without having my IntelliSense flooded?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I'm including the Boost library for the dynamic_bitset and now my IntelliSense is full of a ton of Boost stuff.  Any way to stop this? I'm using VS2012

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense should only list functions in the current namespace. You are most likely using a using directive.